# How do we find the different values for each iteration in rstanarm?

Tags: r, stan, rstan, rstanarm

I did write a basic GLM code in `rstanarm`.  When I execute the following code it is giving the mean of the predictor variables of all the iterations done:

```
  summary(TestGLM) 
  print(TestGLM)
```

I wanted the value of the predictor variables at each and every iteration for my solution. Can anyone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Took a quick look in [the manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstanarm/rstanarm.pdf). Did you have any luck with `prior_summary` and `summary.stanreg`? If not I guess you can `str(TestGLM)` and poke around.

Comment: @EricFail Thanks for your response. I can get the values using str(TestGLM) and also found ggmcmc(TestGLM) for getting the values. I was wondering what does posterior_predict(TestGLM) does as it also giving me the values. Please let me know if you have any idea regarding posterior_predict()

Comment: Have a look at page 23 in the rstanarm manual I linked above.

Comment: @EricFail Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the draws for each of the coefficients as follows:

```
require(rstanarm)

TestGLM <- stan_glm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
draws <- as.data.frame(TestGLM)
print(colnames(draws))
str(draws)

# See http://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/reference/as.matrix.stanreg.html
```